# Select options 2 "columns" well aligned despite left column's longest length

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
<select name="timezones" id="timezones">
    <option value="1">Pacific/Auckland +12:00</option>
    <option value="2">Australia/Brisbane +10:00</option>
    <option value="3">Austrabane +10:00</option>
    <option value="4">Australia +12:00</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var spacesToAdd = 5;
var biggestLength = 0;
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
var len = $(this).text().length;
    if(len > biggestLength){
        biggestLength = len;
    }
});
var padLength = biggestLength + spacesToAdd;
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
    var parts = $(this).text().split('+');
    var strLength = parts[0].length;
    console.log(strLength);
    for(var x=0; x<(padLength-strLength); x++){
        parts[0] += ' ';
    }
    $(this).text(parts[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0')+parts[1]);
});
```

So JS calculates the longest word on the "left" column, and then adds space to the other columns that are shorter to make the right column well aligned. It's not working however and after debugging for a while I can't find out why.

http://jsfiddle.net/ASR2K/352/

Edit: Here's the problem I got: http://screencast.com/t/MMs5sKWsD

Comment: It appears to be working fine on the fiddle. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What are your expected results? From a quick check in the jsfiddle in chrome and IE, I see no obvious problems

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're adding whitespace to the longest option as well as the others. Try skipping that one by checking the length when padding.

Comment: Weird, that's what I get: http://screencast.com/t/MMs5sKWsD

Answer (score 0):

Tried on FireFox and Chrome and both works fine.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put the second column first as I believe it's always of the same length?

Comment: That would be a good idea but in my use cases it's not always the same length, I use the system for other kinds of columns for example the country/city abbreviations instead of just the time

Comment: I know it won't be as pretty as whitespace, but can you replace the additional whitespaces with and underscore?

Comment: I tried but it's the same -- unaligned (less underscores being generated than required)